# Android 10 code to allow external directory access and grant permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-10.0

Good day everyone,
I would like to ask a few questions, if I may. 
I have an app that works on pre-Android 10 phones, but I see that various code changes have been made when accessing external directories. I don't have access to an Android 10 phone, so I have come up with the following code after perusal of many pages on Stackoverflow. I don't know of a way to test it myself, so could someone please kindly let me know what they think of this code:

```
            String imageFileName;
            String timestamp; // creation of the value omitted here


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) 
            {
                imageFileName = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                imageFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            }


                OutputStream fout = null; // Now write out the image to external directory
                File imageFile = new File(imageFileName);

                try {
                    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fout);
                    fout.flush();
                    fout.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                      // do stuff
                }

             // Now, "update" the directory using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile to refresh
             // its contents when viewed on the device

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) 
            {
               MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(activityReference.get(), new String[]{getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
                        {


                        }
                    });
            }
            else // Not Android 10
            {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(activityReference.get(), new String[]{Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
                        {


                        }
                    });
            }
```

The parts above that don't explicitly reference Android 10 work fine

The other questions are about permissions to access the filestore, which I would like to read/write to. I have these declared in the Manifest and currently my code, for pre-Android 10 is

```
    if( (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_ALL);

    }
```

I am loading an image file and, again pre-Android 10, I have

```
   findbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

        }
    });


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    switch(requestCode){

        case 7:

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                Uri PathHolder = data.getData();

                try
                {
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(PathHolder));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   // 
                }

                // Do more image related stuff here

            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Is there anything here that needs to have an "if..then" statement to account for file access in Android 10?
Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: You can download and create an emulator on Android Studio that runs on Android 10 and test your code.

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it doesn't work. Thats why I'm asking here.

Comment: It might be worth troubleshooting why the emulator isn't working. When you develop an app and you want to target a specific Android version, you'll probably need to spend a lot of time debugging various parts of it, and you won't always be able to rely on others to accurately find mistakes in your code.

Comment: You can’t get access for External storage from Android 10. Use MediaStore instead